# How To Make Featured Images In WP Themes Bleed To The Edge

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-featured-image

Hi there I'm in the processes of customizing a WP theme and i am looking at trying to make the featured images that are uploaded to posts bleed to the end of the content area. For a good example take a look at this blog that has the same feature.

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/08/funny-typographic-beard-guide/

the featured image in the url is listed above the post title and you will notice that it does not take up the padding of the content.

Comment: Could you paste the code your currently using here? Or a link to your blog? It should just be a matter of putting the featured image outside particular divs. If you can identify where the padding is being applied, take it out, and then apply only to the divs containing the post content rather than the entire wp_posts section.

Answer (score 0):

The image you were talking about has a specific width and height set as html attributes, which gives it the same width of its' parent, thus it's taking the whole space.

To get a better answer, please post the code of the featured image CSS and HTML.